# Simple tips to reduce coupling

Tags: c#

I have a large .NET web application. The system has projects for different intentions (e.g. CMS, Forum, eCommerce), and I have noticed a (naive) pattern of calling on another project's class. For example, the ecommerce module needs functionality to generate a file on the fly for products, and I call and reference a method in the CMS to do this, because file handling is really a job for the CMS.

Obviously (and I know why), this is bad design and a case of high coupling.

I know a few ways to handle high coupling, like restructuring the project (although I don't really think this is a robust solution), but what else can I do to reduce high coupling? Any simple tips? Also, it would be good to know why/how they reduce coupling. I use .NET 3.5 and Sql Server 2005 so things like JMS (which I keep coming across in my search for tips on this design issue), are not applicable.

Thanks

---

BTW,

One of the reasons I ask this is that I have read the previous questions similar to this but usually if a question that has been asked before is asked again, different tips can be learnt as different people reply to the post.

I know of dependency injection/IOC, but I am interested in the small things that can be done to reduce coupling.

How could I choose between using a static class, or an interface-derived class, or the IOC approach when deciding on *how* to reduce coupling? Also, I could develop a web service which could call a static class - mixing up the approaches in my solution.

The interesting thing is that in my application, I don't want it to be disjointed. So I just have a forum, ecommerce system, and any other module required, but everything has to gel into one site so each module (which is represented as a dedicated project in my Visual Studio solution) needs to know about every other module and work with it. So for example, I might have a module which handles user profiles (working with ASP.NET membership, roles, etc), but this will work with the forum module as a user on the forum will be a registered user on the site (one login throughout), and his or her profile will be coming from the user profile module. This is as opposed to seperate profiles as seen on other sites I've come across).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a layering problem. Your assemblies should have a single dependency cycle - from least stable to most stable. That allows you to version sensibly. Generally, that cycle would be something like UI (least stable) -> Domain Core (stable) -> Data Access (most stable). You can throw in a Utilities or some infrastructre assemblies along the way, but again - they should be considered more stable than the assemblies dependent on them.

I'd guess your App.ECommerce and App.Cms assemblies are more siblings than layers - so you would not want those to depend on each other, but that doesn't mean you can't reuse functionality. For your particular scenario, you need to push the needed functionality down to a Core or Utilities assembly that both ECommerce and Cms can depend on. If it's a specific implementation that ECommerce provides, then you can push an interface or abstract base class to the Core - and have a higher layer (perhaps IoC container) wire up the concrete Cms.FileCreator class to the ECommerce.IFileCreator dependency.

Answer (score 4):

You should expose web services in those projects who will be needed by other projects. This is kind of the base level idea behind SOA. So, I would just create web services and consume them, which will decouple you quite a bit from how you have it now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider starting by doing an "extract interface" refactoring on the tightly coupled pieces. For example, if using the CMS as a backing store, create an interface that can store things, then create a mediator or adapter class that knows about the CMS, but isolate the logic that knows about the storage mechanism details to just that class.

Then, for testing, you can easily substitute an in-memory store or local-filesystem store that doesn't depend on the CMS being up.

Consider using techniques like dependency injection (See StructureMap, Spring.Net, NInject) to simplify instantiation if a simple factory doesn't give you the flexibility you need.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get proper abstractions in place as described by others (interfaces, etc). Program against abstractions, not concretions.
2. Design your classes with Dependency Injection in mind as you have described.
3. Use an [Inversion of Control Container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) as the mortar between the bricks.

[Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity) from the [Patterns & Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx) team complements the Enterprise Library.

Scott Hanselman has a nice [List of .NET Inversion of Control Containers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know anything about .NET, but how about refactoring common code into a separate, underlaying project/layer? Loads of stuff in a web app can be done generically to suit both a CMS, a forum and eCommerce, writing to a file is a perfect example.

Another approach could be to see the forum and eCommerce as modules in a CMS, which would also make sense. Then they could safely use specified API:s of the CMS.