# ASP.NET Core - Best way to reduce dependencies in business services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, azure-servicebus-queues

It's a web application running ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 that started as an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and has been growing for 5 years.

I have defined services for different business processes but at some point, many of those services depend on each other. The end result is services with many dependencies and some circular references.

For example, service A performs an action and then it has trigger another action in service B. And then end result has to be sent back to the user. This is a simplification, of course.

In some cases, I'm using Azure Service Bus to decouple the processes. That way, service A performs an action and then queues an action that triggers a process in service B. Then service B is gonna send an HTTP request to the web application to notify the users. This approach worked out well but I'm not sure if I should apply it system-wide. It adds complexity for sure, as debugging is not that simple.

I know someone will say "use Microservices" but that's a big change and for now I need to have one datbase for all the processes.

I found the request-response pattern applied to Azure Service Bus to be really useful but I couldn't find any code examples. Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions#request-response-pattern

[image: I was thinking about something like this but I couldn't any good code example]

Any recommendations are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a very complex problem you have encountered and to say there is an obvious solution would be wrong.

Recently I was working for the company project that had an intention to escape, such called [Death Star Architecture](https://dzone.com/articles/navigating-the-microservice-deathstar-with-deployh), which is somewhat close to the problem you have. To escape coupling between projects/services, the company decided to move to expansive solutions based on Azure Microservices ([Logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-logic-apps/4-when-to-use-logic-apps), [Data Factories](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/#features), [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/#updates-announcements), etc.).
Although it's worth mentioning that the solution solved the issues with couplings because with Azure Microservices, you can easily switch between solutions without the need to worry about dependencies.

There are quite a lot of articles about the good and bad sides of the microservices, and you should examine all the pros and cons before moving forward with them. Also, check the business needs, are there available time and resources for that or not.

One other thing that I can suggest you look at is the [reactive programming approach](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/06/30/5-things-to-know-about-reactive-programming/).

Also, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311714/simple-tips-to-reduce-coupling) thread. There are a couple of good suggestions, worth mentioning.

Comment: I added a picture to the question. I found the request-response pattern using sessions in Azure Message Bus to be really useful to achieve what I need but I couldn't find any code examples.